# Searching extreme points of polyhedron

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, homework, computational-geometry

In my Uni, my scientific professor asked me to make some researches about the extreme points of polyhedrals. And I did them. I found that there is still no code in public for searching extreme points for polyhedral with n dimensions (n - x's), but polyhedrons are everywhere (CV, game theories, etc.). I wrote a function for this task and made a python library (also there are matrix and array combination maker functions).

All I want is to make this code more optimal and compatible for all python versions (I have some troubles that some times happen when I install it by "pip install lin", but other times no). I want to make the life of people easier and make it more comfortable.

I am asking for you to test this function on your computer and write if you have any bugs, fails or thoughts on how to make it better. I am open to constructive criticism and non-constructive too (it will help to understand if somebody needs it or that is just a waste of time).

All the examples, instructions and code on my GitHub: [https://github.com/r4ndompuff/polyhedral_set](https://github.com/r4ndompuff/polyhedral_set/tree/c61eb1264a937cd0c87771bdb3a61c452455a314)

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import math
import re

def permutation(m,n):
    return math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(n-m)*math.factorial(m))

def matrix_combinations(matr,n):
    timed = list(map(list, it.combinations(matr, n)))
    for i in range(n):
        timed[i][i][i] = np.asscalar(timed[i][i][i])
    all = np.array(list(timed))
    return all

def array_combinations(arr,n):
    timed = list(map(list, it.combinations(arr, n)))
    for i in range(n):
        timed[i][i] = np.asscalar(timed[i][i])
    all = np.array(list(timed))
    return all

def check_extreme(matr, arr, x, sym_comb, m):
    sym_comb = sym_comb.replace(']', '')
    sym_comb = sym_comb.replace('[', '')
    sym_comb = re.split("[ ,]", sym_comb)
    for i in range(m):
        td_answer = sum(matr[i]*x)
        if sym_comb[i] == '>':
            if td_answer <= arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '>=':
            if td_answer < arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '<':
            if td_answer >= arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '<=':
            if td_answer > arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '=':
            if td_answer != arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '!=':
            if td_answer == arr[i]:
                return 0
        else:
            return 0
    return 1

def extreme_points(m,n,A,b,sym_comb):
    # Input
    A = np.array(A).reshape(m,n)
    b = np.array(b).reshape(m,1)
    # Proccess
    ans_comb = np.zeros((1,n))
    arr_comb = array_combinations(b,n)
    matr_comb = matrix_combinations(A,n)
    for i in range(int(permutation(n,m))):
        if np.linalg.det(matr_comb[i]) != 0:
            x = np.linalg.solve(matr_comb[i],arr_comb[i])
            ans_comb = np.vstack([ans_comb,x])
    ans_comb = np.delete(ans_comb, (0), axis=0)
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(ans_comb)):
        if check_extreme(A, b, ans_comb[j], sym_comb, m):
            ans_comb = ans_comb
            j = j + 1
        else:
            ans_comb = np.delete(ans_comb, (j), axis=0)
    # Output
    return ans_comb
```

And I am uploading some more tests. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRl4.jpg

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what exactly is going on, from a math standpoint? Is this actually a polyhedron, or a polytope? In how many dimensions? By "extreme", what do you mean? Euclidean norm from (the origin, an arbitrary point)?

Comment: "there is still no code in public for searching extreme points for polyhedral with n dimensions" - I can nearly guarantee that that isn't the case.

Comment: @Reinderien I am still in the process of deciphering the question. I have a math background, and I share the mother tongue with OP. My impression is that by extremal points OP means the vertices of a simplex where a certain linear form (defined by `A`, `b`, and the condition) achieves an extremum. I could be wrong.

Comment: @vnp That's kind of what I guessed, and if that's the case, linear programming is a quite well-established field already - with some stuff built right into scipy.

Comment: @Reinderien Agreed. Still deciphering.

Comment: @AndrewLovyagin When I run, I get this error: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc solve1`

Comment: This occurs for both Python 3.7 and 2.7. However, I'm using numpy-1.16.2, which I strongly suggest you adopt.

Comment: @Reinderien
I was using this article (https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ilp152/wiki.files/hwk2.pdf) to understand what is polyhedron.
And I am using n-dimensions (that means you can put any positive integer number in the first and second argument of the function). 
For the solving system of equations (Ax=b) I am using numpy.linalg.solve(), but before I am checking if matrix A, not a degenerate matrix.
I don't know what is polytope, but I google it, and now I am interested :0

Comment: @vnp
I was using this article to understand it from math point: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ilp152/wiki.files/hwk2.pdf

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's linear programming

Comment: @Reinderien
Thank you for your report. I will try to update this program to work with latest preinstalled numpy (mine is 1.15.4).

From the math point: I am making all combinations of matrix A NxN (where N is a number of dimensions). Then I am solving each system of equations for the same combinations of vector b and checking the answers if they are really an extreme points.

Comment: Can you explicitly define `w`, `x`, `u` and `U` as seen in your docs?

Comment: Look up "convex hull" to find examples of getting the boundaries (extreme points) of a series of points (e.g. the vertices of your polyhedral)

Comment: @Reinderien I wrote it by hand on example to made it more explicit: https://imgur.com/oZF9uf4

Comment: @AJD Yep, I was reading about it, when was writing the code, thank you. I will try to dig deeper into this theme.

Comment: Given the number of comments already, let's please continue this at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92760/searching-extreme-points-of-polyhedron

Answer (score 5):

I created a rudimentary pull request to your GitHub repo. I won't show all of the content here except for the main file:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
from math import factorial
import re


def permutation(m, n):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(n - m) * factorial(m))


def matrix_combinations(matr, n):
    timed = list(map(list, it.combinations(matr, n)))
    return np.array(list(timed))


def array_combinations(arr, n):
    timed = list(map(list, it.combinations(arr, n)))
    return np.array(list(timed))


def check_extreme(matr, arr, x, sym_comb, m):
    sym_comb = sym_comb.replace(']', '')
    sym_comb = sym_comb.replace('[', '')
    sym_comb = re.split("[ ,]", sym_comb)
    for i in range(int(m)):
        td_answer = sum(matr[i] * x)
        if sym_comb[i] == '>':
            if td_answer <= arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '>=':
            if td_answer < arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '<':
            if td_answer >= arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '<=':
            if td_answer > arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '=':
            if td_answer != arr[i]:
                return 0
        elif sym_comb[i] == '!=':
            if td_answer == arr[i]:
                return 0
        else:
            return 0
    return 1


def extreme_points(A, b, sym_comb):
    # Input
    A = np.array(A)
    b = np.array(b)
    m, n = A.shape
    # Process
    ans_comb = np.zeros((1, n))
    arr_comb = array_combinations(b, n)
    matr_comb = matrix_combinations(A, n)
    for i in range(int(permutation(n, m))):
        if np.linalg.det(matr_comb[i]) != 0:
            x = np.linalg.solve(np.array(matr_comb[i], dtype='float'),
                                np.array(arr_comb[i], dtype='float'))
            ans_comb = np.vstack([ans_comb, x])
    ans_comb = np.delete(ans_comb, 0, axis=0)
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(ans_comb)):
        if check_extreme(A, b, ans_comb[j], sym_comb, m):
            ans_comb = ans_comb
            j += 1
        else:
            ans_comb = np.delete(ans_comb, j, axis=0)
    # Output
    return ans_comb
```

Notable changes:

- Do a direct import of `factorial`
- Don't call `asscalar`, since it's both unneeded and deprecated
- Don't call a variable `all`, since that shadows a Python built-in
- Don't need to explicitly pass array dimensions, nor do you need to reshape the arrays
- Drop redundant parens around some expressions
- Use `+=` where applicable
- Fix up almost all PEP8 issues, except for your capital letter `A`, which is fine in context

This doesn't solve the bigger issue that you should replace 99% of this with a call to scipy. I'll do that separately (I suspect that @vnp is, as well).

Comment: Thank you!
In meantime I made it work with any NumPy version now (about loop error you report).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the same function in scipy. Can you provide me the name of function?

Comment: @AndreyLovyagin https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Comment: Thank you very much for all that you have done!
Also, I checked scipy.optimize.linprog() function and I can't really understand how it can replace much of the code. I will learn and read more about it, but on first sight, it looks like it can't solve non-equational system (I mean not '=', but any sign, e.g. '>='), that is why I can't see how I can find extreme points by it.

Comment: Read about the A_ub, b_ub arguments.

Comment: Okay, I have checked it fully. Scipy functions didn't do the same. Scipy very useful for optimizing, but my task not only linear programming but also math programming, that's why A_ub and b_ub didn't help (I checked link examples, their answers are not extreme points for any inequality or equality.

Comment: My mistake. They are able to find an extreme points, but only one (cuz optimization). In an example, in scipy docs there are 2 more extreme points, but they output only one.